# Most efficient way to log Simulink signals

Tags: matlab, logging, simulink

Wondering what is the best way to log Simulink signals which outputs large data sets (couple of gigs worth) in a way that is RAM efficient and with minimal sacrifice to simulation speed?

Answer (score 1):

The most memory efficient way that I know is using [`To File`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/tofile.html) block. It incrementally writes the result to the file, minimizing the memory impact of logging.